# haskell expected type trouble

Tags: haskell, types

new to Haskell and functional programing...in the learning process. What is wrong with this code:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char
import System.Environment

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   progName <- getProgName
   content <- readFile $ head args
   putStrLn $ show $ getWordsInfo content

getWordsInfo = let
                  wordList = filter (\x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) . words
               in foldl foldingFunction 0 wordList
                 where foldingFunction acc tWord = acc + length tWord
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[[a0]]'
            with actual type `String -> [[Char]]'
In the third argument of `foldl', namely `wordList'
In the expression: foldl foldingFunction 0 wordList
In the expression:
  let
    wordList = filter (\ x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) . words
  in foldl foldingFunction 0 wordList
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the getWordsInfo function? Getting the number of characters in words with a length greater than 2 which are all alphanumeric? If so then you don't really need to use a foldl, you can just use sum.

Comment: Nevermind, in folding function I could do other stuff that return Int, just I am wondering why this won't compile....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using point free notation incorrectly.

The only line of this that is wrong is:

`let wordList = filter (\x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) . words`

The error message is saying that when you call wordList it hasn't been applied to enough arguments, it is expecting a list of lists, but instead has been given a function which takes a string and produces a list of lists. So, we simply need to give the wordList function the input string.

You can rewrite it two ways:

The first is by explicitly specifying the argument:

```
getWordsInfo xs = let wordList = filter (\x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) (words xs)
                  in foldl foldingFunction 0 wordList
                    where foldingFunction acc tWord = acc + length tWord
```

The second is by keeping the point free bit not in a let binding:

```
getWordsInfo = foldl foldingFunction 0 . filter (\x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) . words
                    where foldingFunction acc tWord = acc + length tWord
```

Your folding function is taking the length of each word and summing them up, which can be simplified by mapping over the list, and taking the length, then summing the list.

```
getWordsInfo = sum . map length . filter (\x -> length x > 2 && all isAlpha x) . words
```

And that line is getting a bit long, so we should probably factor some of it out into another definition giving us finally:

```
import Data.Char (isAlpha)

getWordsInfo = sum . map length . filter isLongWord . words
    where isLongWord x = length x > 2 && all isAlpha x
```

Usage:

```
λ> getWordsInfo "apple banana orange a a b b punctuation!!"
17
λ> getWordsInfo "aa bb cc"
0
λ> getWordsInfo "!!!"
0
λ> getWordsInfo "apple"
5
λ>
```